# Laravel sendOutpuTo not recording to specified file

Tags: laravel

Recently I started using the task scheduler and considering that I would like to log scheduler errors separately from the frontend errors, I found the `sendOutputTo` helper which looked like exactly what I needed.

My "schedule" method in Kernel.php is like this (and there is no other jobs there):

```
$schedule->command('check:dead')->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/checkdead.log'), false);
```

When running Laravel's `schedule:run` the job itself is processed perfectly. If there is no checkdead.log file in the logs folder Laravel creates it as expected, but all log entries are still recorded in `logs/laravel.log` file.

logging.php file extract ('channels' array is unchanged from the default):

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
```

.env file extract:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

'single' channel config in 'channels' array:

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
],
```

The code in the Command class to Log is plain vanilla:

```
Log::error('Config table does not contain all required notification days records.');
```

As I mentioned, everything is working fine: the job itself and the logging instructions. The only issue is that the application is recording the log entries in laravel.log file instead of the one I defined in the `sendOutputTo` helper.

I believe I am missing some kind of configuration variable, but I couldn't find anything in Laravel's documentation or googling around.

I understand that I shouldn't change the driver default path variable because this would apply to every log recorded by jobs or frontend application.

Any clues?

I expect Laravel to record the log entries in the file specified in `sendOutputTo` helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log isn't output. Output is anything sent to the console, like echo. Create a new log channel, and use that in your log command. So if you create a new channel called `console_log`

```
'console_log' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/console.log'),
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
],
```

Then you can use it in your command

```
Log::channel('console_log')->error('Config table does not contain all required notification days records.');
```